# ffplay, rtsp and tcp transport protocol

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a problem on connect to a rtsp camera using `ffplay`.
The camera is under a router that permits only the TCP protocol.
I can watch the camera using `ffplay` only if I am in the same network of the camera.
So, when I am out, using this command line

```
ffplay rtsp://address:554/onvif1
```

or this

```
ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://address:554/onvif1
```

I cannot watch the camera.
This is the output of ffplay (the latest).

```
[rtsp @ 059ee680] Nonmatching transport in server reply  0B f=0/0
rtsp://address:554:/onvif1: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Trying with VLC and I can watch the camera without any problem, both when I am in the same network or when I am out. The VLC output says that VLC uses TCP.
Has someone got a suggestion?

Comment: should work. need more verbose logs please.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66280861/1207193) might help. Your problem likes like mine, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as you can see below vlc works without any problem.
FFMpeg works only with a local camera but not with a remote camera. Forcing tcp as rtsp protocol seems to have no effect.

**try to capture a remote camera (doesn't work)**

```
denis@tomcat:~/Scaricati/ffmpeg-git-20181227-amd64-static$ **./ffmpeg -v verbose -i rtsp://address:554/onvif1 a.avi**
ffmpeg version N-47834-gb5e0a0fe3a-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100
  libavcodec     58. 42.104 / 58. 42.104
  libavformat    58. 25.100 / 58. 25.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[tcp @ 0x5f86700] Starting connection attempt to address port 554
```

**try to capture a remote camera forcing tcp (doesn't work)**

```
denis@tomcat:~/Scaricati/ffmpeg-git-20181227-amd64-static$ **./ffmpeg -v verbose -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://address:554/onvif1 a.avi**
ffmpeg version N-47834-gb5e0a0fe3a-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100
  libavcodec     58. 42.104 / 58. 42.104
  libavformat    58. 25.100 / 58. 25.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[tcp @ 0x5515740] Starting connection attempt to address port 554
```

**Using vlc (works)**

```
denis@tomcat:~/Scaricati/ffmpeg-git-20181227-amd64-static$ **vlc -v**
VLC media player 3.0.3 Vetinari (revision 3.0.3-1-0-gc2bb759264)
[000056417a4461a0] main libvlc: Esecuzione di vlc con l'interfaccia predefinita. Usa 'cvlc' per utilizzare vlc senza interfaccia.
[000056417a4da540] main playlist: playlist is empty
[00007fcd00000eb0] live555 demux warning: no data received in 10s. Switching to TCP
[00007fcd0000b2d0] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[000056417a505bf0] pulse audio output warning: starting late (-591 us)
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-260338): playing silence
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback too late (67682): up-sampling
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback too early (-60916): down-sampling
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-191284): playing silence
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too late (252312): flushing buffers
[000056417a505bf0] pulse audio output warning: starting late (-5953 us)
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-701316): playing silence
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-332484): playing silence
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback too late (125861): up-sampling
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too late (297954): flushing buffers
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-993047): playing silence
[00007fcd0000b2d0] avcodec decoder warning: thread type 1: disabling hardware acceleration
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback too late (107083): up-sampling
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too late (235778): flushing buffers
[00007fcce0001cc0] egl_x11 gl error: cannot select OpenGL API
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-657714): playing silence
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too late (238668): flushing buffers
[00007fccf8160b40] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 691 ms)
[00007fccf8160b40] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 491 ms)
[00007fccf8160b40] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 290 ms)
[00007fccf8160b40] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 89 ms)
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-652182): playing silence
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback too late (72927): up-sampling
[000056417a505bf0] main audio output warning: playback too late (98876): up-sampling
[000056417a4da540] main playlist: end of playlist, exiting
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66280861/1207193) might help. VLC uses `openRTSP` more tolerant to RTSP misues. Maybe you should hack ffmpeg like I did.