# FFMPEG: 'Nonmatching transport in server reply' But openRTSP works

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavformat, rtsp-client, openrtsp

I bought a cheap chinese ip camera (*GWIPC-26xxx*/*Yoosee*). I want to record its stream with ffmpeg.

On *FFMPEG* I manage to make it work **only** using the **RTSP/UDP** transport protocol, like bellow. It also plays flawlessly on VLC.

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://admin:pass@192.168.0.103:554/onvif1 streamfile.mkv
```

`pass` is a password defined on the android camera app client.

But ***I highly prefer the RTSP/TCP transport*** because using UDP the images are ***frequently*** corrupted. Images that appear smeared and teared. So I tested almost anything and even compiled `FFMPEG` from source using the [latest repository](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg). But nothing makes ffmpeg work, android or windows. If use `-rtsp_transport tcp` I allways end-up receiving:

```
[rtsp @ 0xxxxxxx] Nonmatching transport in server reply
```

Finally discovered [openRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/) that uses the same library that VLC uses. With it I managed to make it connect using RTSP/TCP (*after compiling from source*).

```
openRTSP -n -D 1 -c -B 10000000 -b 10000000 -q -Q -F cam_file \ 
-d 60 -P 30 -t -u admin pass rtsp://192.168.0.103:554/onvif1
```

More details on `openRTSP` params [here](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/).

The weirdest part is the comparison of the ***RTSP setup messages*** (FFMPEG vs openRTSP). It seams clear that the ip camera server supports RTP/AVP/TCP. RTP interleaved into the existing TCP connection.

And looking the source code of `ffmpeg/libavformat/rtsp.c` it seams ffmpeg is having some problem indentifying it?

```
...
if (reply->transports[0].lower_transport != lower_transport) {
    av_log(s, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Nonmatching transport in server reply\n");
    err = AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
    goto fail;
}
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [Quoting Wisdom](https://superuser.com/a/921385/263459)

> IP cameras are of varying quality, some behaving erratically in my experience. Dealing with their RTSP streams requires a dose of fault-tolerance.
> This appears to be a byproduct of the low-end of the CCTV industry playing fast and loose with standards, **RTSP** and ONVIF **being** the two **most frequently abused**.
> Fortunately, you can usually work around these problems. Unless your IP cameras and controller are all designed to play nicely together, only use ONVIF for once-only discovery and settings management.

#### FFMPEG not very tolerant in RTSP setup

After struggling I started comparing the RTSP/***SETUP*** messages between `openRTSP` and `ffmpeg`. `openRTSP` by default already outputs a lot of verbose diagnostic.

**openRTSP**

`openRTSP` sends the commands `OPTIONS`, `DESCRIBE` and then `SETUP`. The SETUP messages were:

```
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.0.103:554/onvif1/track2 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 6
Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="HIipCamera", nonce="ddd21dbd0620b6fb4b1f9bcbb06340a0", uri="rtsp://192.168.0.103:554/onvif1", response="91d9c611aa004eeb1390b3fbb9373648"
User-Agent: ./openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2021.02.11)
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=2-3
Session: 3a4d2e6d
```

response by camera:

```
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 6
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;destination=192.168.0.100;source=192.168.0.103;interleaved=2-3
Session: 3a4d2e6d;timeout=60
```

**FFMPEG**

For `FFMPEG` you have to use `-v 9 and -loglevel 99` params to see RTSP messages. It only sent a `DESCRIBE` request is:

```
DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.0.103:554/onvif1 RTSP/1.0
Accept: application/sdp
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: Lavf58.67.100
```

response by camera:

```
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;destination=192.168.0.100;source=192.168.0.103;interleaved=0-1
Session: 37287775;timeout=60
```

#### RTSP abused and FFMPEG hacking-Solution

Comparing the messages it's clear the camera can connect using RTSP/AVP/TCP interleaved TCP. But we can see by the camera answer that in the *'Transport:' line* it doesn't include **'TCP'** after **'RTP/AVP'** as it was requested. Like:

```
Transport: RTP/AVP/('TCP' missing here);....
```

I analysed the code on and `ffmpeg/libavformat/rtsp.c` and found the intuitive calling sequence: `ff_rtsp_connect`, `ff_rtsp_make_setup_request`, `ff_rtsp_send_cmd`, `ff_rtsp_read_reply` and `ff_rtsp_parse_line`. Inside this last one I found `rtsp_parse_transport` and the following code:

```
if (!av_strcasecmp(lower_transport, "TCP"))
    th->lower_transport = RTSP_LOWER_TRANSPORT_TCP;
else
    th->lower_transport = RTSP_LOWER_TRANSPORT_UDP;
```

`lower_transport` is the text parsed after `'RTP/AVP;'` in my case being `""`  empty char string since the camera server did not include it.

I insertd `|| !av_strcasecmp(lower_transport, "")` in the code. Making it assume that the transport is `RTSP_LOWER_TRANSPORT_TCP` when `lower_transport` is ommited. Like bellow:

```
if (!av_strcasecmp(lower_transport, "TCP") || !av_strcasecmp(lower_transport, ""))
    th->lower_transport = RTSP_LOWER_TRANSPORT_TCP;
else
    th->lower_transport = RTSP_LOWER_TRANSPORT_UDP;
```

This tiny patch (git) for ffmpeg is available [here](https://github.com/eusoubrasileiro/motion_server_nvr/blob/jetson-nano/ansible/roles/jnano/files/RTSP_lower_transport_TCP.patch). Apply using `git am < RTSP_lower_transport_TCP.patch` on ffmpeg git repo.

#### After recompiling: FFMPEG is working perfectly!

I ***hacked FFMPEG*** making it *tolerant with the RTSP abuse* the camera server was doing.  Since my version of FFMPEG will only run on my unused android tv (as a cctv/nvr camera server) this won't create any other problems.

A better solution would be the FFMPEG ([Ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9107)) consider also the case of *a missing lower transport* on a rtsp server answer. Then compare with the client-sent request to define whether the lower transport was ommitted. And try to connect with it.

### Advice

Probably if you reached here your ip camera **might** be suffering from some RTSP abuse. I recommend you to try using `openRTSP` first to see if it manages to connect. If so, then try to debug its RTSP/setup messages. It's possible that some custom or hacking solution exists if you modify (at your own risk) the `ffmpeg/libavformat/rtsp.c` code. Or you might/should use live555 library, VLC or mplayer.

Comment: Applying this patch made it work like a charm. Thank you so much for sharing.

Comment: @Vinicius Tinti às ordens